# Special characters are not getting identified by sqlite

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Am using sql query to get the data.. And my query is

```
select * from green where outlineDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' and outlineTitle = 'That's Alright'
```

The `outlineTitle` got single quote, that is not getting data from the db eventhough db has data.If i put another `outlineTitle` without any special characters, its working...

Please help me out guys.... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your query improperly. Never use a string format to build a query string. Most likely you are doing something like:

```
NSString *title = ... // some title that might have "special characters"
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * ... and outlineTitle='%@'", title];
```

This is a very bad way to create the query. The proper way is to use prepared statements.

```
NSString *title = ... // some title that might have "special characters"
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, "SELECT * FROM green WHERE outlineTitle = ?", -1, &stmt, nil);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

By using `?` in your query and then using the proper `sqlite3_bind_xxx` method, all values are properly escaped and quoted. This fixes the problem with single quotes and other characters. This also fixes potential SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What if the string ends with characters either ' or "
For me its failing any clue to handle this?

Comment: @Dhanunjay That's the point of using sqlite3_bind_text. It properly escapes all special characters.